# Phaser: Change anchor from Body?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

is it possible in Phaser to change the anchor from the body to center like from Object?

This doesnt work:

Sprite.body.anchor.x = 0.5;

Comment: i dont understand why you need to do it from the body 
the body take sprite position i mean the body will fit the sprite

Comment: But i want to have the collision on another position then the sprite

Comment: You know a possibility to do this? Precising the example: I have Player which has a anchor on his foots when he is walking from left to right. But when i jump i want to change the anchor from the body to the mid of the character.

Comment: i dont think so however there are other ways like making empty sprite and set its body then attach it to another sprite on the x , y you want relative to sprite

Comment: but why not make body for whole Player  complex physic body using physic  editor software

Comment: I use the Arcade Physic at the moment. Is it with this not possible? Should i change the physic to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You should write:

sprite.anchor.setTo(x,y);

or:

sprite.anchor.set(x);

if you wish to anchor your sprite in the same x & y coordinates, i.e.: sprite.anchor.set(0.5); places the anchor in the exact middle of the sprite, horizontally and vertically.

This should work fine in the latest version of Phaser.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have some options to change the anchor point of a sprite:

```
// Set the anchor point to the top left of the sprite (default value)
   this.sprite.anchor.setTo(0, 0);

// Set the anchor point to the top right of the sprite
   this.sprite.anchor.setTo(1, 0);

// Set the anchor point to the bottom left of the sprite
   this.sprite.anchor.setTo(0, 1);

// Set the anchor point to the bottom right of the sprite
   this.sprite.anchor.setTo(1, 1);

// Set the anchor point to the center of the sprite
   this.sprite.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Phaser 3, we can use [setOrigin()](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#setOrigin__anchor) on the sprite (or game object)

```
sprite.setOrigin(0.5); // set both x and y to 0.5 
sprite.setOrigin(0.5, 1); // set x to 0.5 and y to 1
```

Phaser 3 also has a [good example here](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/transform/originxy) on how to use it